# adding machines to VPN gateway inside Azure

Tags: iptables, vpn, routing, azure

Testing VPN service inside azure I finished to setup a connection between my cloud and azure to see azure machines with Site-to-Site connection, but now Im looking how I can config azure VM to use the VPN to send traffic from specific pool Ips.

My schema

- My internal pool 10.130.0.0/24
- Azure net 10.0.0.0/24
- VPN 10.0.19.0/24
- GatewaySubnet 10.0.20.0/24

I know for example using Iptables routing but I don't know inside azure how to add VM to the VPN. All examples I found was to connect to Azure, but not in opposite sense. I need to use UDR?

Other checks were:

-VM can't see VPN gateway using ping.I added route to UDR but not seems to have effect.

-Adding a route using Public IP from gateway not connect

-I don't know If traffic needs to go using GatewaySubnet pool or vpn pool.

Thanks!

Comment: I have some doubts. 1. Your Gateway subnet(10.0.20.0/24) in your Azure VNet(10.0.0.0/24)? But, if Gateway subnet is inside VNet, you Vnet should be (10.0.0.0/16). If my understanding is right. You could create a VNet(10.0.0.0/16). Gateway subnet(10.0.20.0/24) and create a VM subnet(10.0.21.0/24). 2. My internal pool, do you mean your local subnet?

Comment: Based on my knowledge, when you create a Site-to-Site VPN, your local could connect the whole VNet, you could create a new subnet and create VM in the subnet.

Comment: Sorry, I confuse vnet with subnet. vnet Azure has 10.0.0.0/16 and subnet 10.0.0.0/24. GatewaySubnet has defined 10.0.20.0/24 and local Gateway is only used to make the tunnel with other side (my internal cloud) with public IP and subnet 10.130.0.0/24

Comment: You had better edit your question about this.

Comment: According to your description, your local subnet is `10.130.0.0/24`. If this is right. You Azure VNet could not select `10.0.0.0/16`. Local subnet and Azure Vnet subnet could not polymerization.

Comment: If I understand, vnet from azure needs to include the pool of the net used in the other part of the vpn? If this is the case, you can't do a vpn connection If your local network (using this schema) use 192.168.0.0/24 no?

Comment: By default, your local pool could connect VNet's all subnet.  You don't need do anything.

Comment: Hi, you could refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal).

Comment: Exactly. And with this howto vpn is working and I can connect from 10.130.0.0/24 to 10.0.0.0/24 but I can't connect in the opposite sense. This is the problem and in this howto local gateway not has references to azure nets, only client nets

Comment: But I think your Vnet and your Azure subnet could not use `10.0.0.0/16` and `10.0.0.0/24` Please check `Make sure that the ranges you specify here do not overlap with ranges of other networks that you want to connect to. Azure will route the address range that you specify to the on-premises VPN device IP address.`. Your local address and Azure Vnet address have overlap.

Comment: You could test Azure VNet select `192.168.0.0/16`. I think it works for you.

Comment: well, in my case I understand that I need to change azure vnet to 10.0.0.0/8 to include 10.130.0.0 vpn net. correct? Im not using 192.168.0.0 inside local net, reference was only  to understand the problem

Comment: If my understanding is right? Your local subnet is `10.130.0.0/24`. Right? Sorry, I think I need to confirm this.

Comment: Well, I modified adress space to 10.0.0.0/8 to have space inside for all Ips. If I connect to 10.0.0.5 and making traceroute to 10.130.0.85 seems how there is no route to this host. Im checking traceroute command and route command and not appears any reference to the vpn gateway. Which steps can I do to know how vpn route traffic inside subnets? I know netwatcher, but I understand that Im making a basic vpon connection and I can't see changes in route tables

Comment: I tested how I can't arrive using ping between azure machine (10.0.0.5) to my local network (10.130.0.85). I monitored using tcpdump and I only receive packets from azure Gw. How can I know the private Ip used by this gateway to config some UDR? Now my feeling is that I have the VPN nodes isolated, they not receive any internal traffic

Comment: Hi, based on my knowledge, your local IP and Azure VNet Ip address overlap. It does not allow by Azure. So, you could not ping. Azure site-to-site VPN could create successful, but there are IP overlaps, you could not communication with each other.

Comment: You should plan your Virtual Network not use `10.0.*.*`. You could use `172.0.0.0/8`. Note, this is Azure VNet, not your local subnet.

Comment: Sorry, I need go home in my country, I will test your scenario in my lab, also. I suggest you could use `172.0.0.0/8` or `192.0.0.0/8` as Azure VNet.

Comment: Hi, can you concret any test to confirm this?

Comment: After some tests, I confirm that change space adress to 10.0.0.0/8 produce overlap so I configured /16 again. I weas testing and seems how other problem i justly that I can arrive from azure servers to vpn local net via ping, but vpn servers no forward traffic to my local GW and I can't arrive to other servers, so I need support with iptables :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you setup your VPN Gateway, you should have had to configure a "local gateway"  If you correctly configured your internal pool in that construct, routing will just work.

Comment: yes, but guide not use local network gateway how something for your azure network. [guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-resource-manager-cli)

Comment: Step 5 is the local gateway step